# Liquibase Missing Environment Vars

Tags: java, google-bigquery, liquibase, versioning

I'm going through the following demo for setting up liquibase versioning with big query:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/version-control-of-bigquery-schema-changes-with-liquibase-ddc7092d6d1d
but I'm getting an error when running the following command:

```
java -jar liquibase-core-4.6.2.jar --changeLogFile=create_table.sql update
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find LIQUIBASE_HOME environment variable
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseLauncher.main(LiquibaseLauncher.java:36)
```

I understand I need to set an environment variable most likely, but I'm worried that I'm missing something because the demo/tutorial didn't mention any environment variables, and I can't find any setup instructions for liquibase envvars online either.

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: This is occuring only in the latest versions of liquibase ie 4.x The previous versions 3.x work well. Did you get any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the source code, LiquibaseLauncher.java, it seems liquibase only looks in particular directories for its jar files relative to `LIQUIBASE_HOME`. You need to add the jar to one of those dirs. You also need to set `LIQUIBASE_HOME`

```bash
mkdir -p internal/lib
mv liquibase-core-4.6.2.jar internal/lib
export LIQUIBASE_HOME='.'
java -jar internal/lib/liquibase-core-4.6.2.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

The best would be to have a look at the examples in their [Github Repo](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/tree/c9ac055826235eeaad60504a5efe2ca01de16e31/liquibase-core/src/main/resources/liquibase/examples) providing cmd scripts to run it in Windows / Linux.
Basically setting the LIQUIBASE_HOME should be sophisticated.